# Using If statement in while loop, blackjack game

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, boolean

At the end stages for finishing my Black-Jack game for school.
I seem to be running into a problem while trying to program the logic.

Basically the dealer will only hit if their cards are <= 16, for some reason the if statement for this isn't working and the dealer just hits all the time or stays all the time, regardless of the value of their cards... I know it's probably something simple but I can't seem to find it.

Also the dealer isn't busting when his card values are over 21.

**main** (PROBLEMS ARE HERE)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class game {
public static String name;

public static void main(String[]args){

    deck doc = new deck();
    dealer dealer = new dealer(doc);

    Scanner nameScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int money = 200;

    System.out.println("Welcome to BlackJack!" + "\n\n" + "Your balance: $" + money + "\n\n" + "What is your name? ");
    name = nameScanner.nextLine();

    dealer.start();

    dealer.dealDealer();
    dealer.dealPlayer();
    dealer.dealDealer();
    dealer.dealPlayer();


    boolean dealerStay = false;
    boolean playerStay = false;
    boolean allStay = false;
    boolean tie = false;

    while(true){

        System.out.println(dealer.toString());
        Scanner gameScanner = new Scanner(System.in);   

        System.out.println("\nWould you like to Hit(H) or Stay(S)? ");

        String hos = gameScanner.nextLine();

        //Players & Dealer hit logic
        if(hos.equalsIgnoreCase("h")) {
            dealer.dealPlayer();
        }
        //Player bust
        if(dealer.getPlayerHandValue() > 21){
            System.out.println("*****YOU LOSE\n*****You bust with " + dealer.getPlayerHandValue() + "\n*****Dealer wins by default");
            break;
        }
        //Stay logic
        if(hos.equalsIgnoreCase("s")){
            playerStay = true;
        }
        //Dealer hit logic PROBLEM HERE
        if(playerStay == true && dealer.getDealerHandValue() <= 16){
            dealer.dealDealer();
            System.out.println("\n*****Dealer hit\n");
        }
        //Dealer stay logic PROBLEM HERE
        if (playerStay == true && dealer.getDealerHandValue() > 16){
            System.out.println("\n*****Dealer stayed\n");
            dealerStay = true;
        }
        //Dealer bust PROBLEM HERE
        if(dealer.getDealerHandValue() > 21){
            System.out.println("*****YOU WIN\n *****Dealer busts");
            break;
        }





        }
    }
}
```

**Constructors** (if you need them)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class dealer {

deck deck = new deck();
String dealerTopCardString = "";
card playerHandCard;
card dealerHandCard;
ArrayList<card> dealerHand = new ArrayList<card>();
ArrayList<card> playerHand = new ArrayList<card>();

public dealer(deck cards) {
    deck = cards;

}

public void start() {
    dealerHand = new ArrayList<card>();
    playerHand = new ArrayList<card>();
}

public String getPlayerHand() {

    String playerHandString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < playerHand.size(); i++) {
        playerHandCard = playerHand.get(i);
        card card = new card(playerHandCard.getValue(),
                playerHandCard.getSuit());
        playerHandString += "\n";
        playerHandString += card.getValue();
        playerHandString += "\t";
        playerHandString += card.getSuit();
    }
    return playerHandString;

}

public String getDealerHand() {

    String dealerHandString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < dealerHand.size(); i++) {
        dealerHandCard = dealerHand.get(i);
        card card = new card(dealerHandCard.getValue(),
                dealerHandCard.getSuit());
        dealerHandString += "\n";
        dealerHandString += card.getValue();
        dealerHandString += "\t";
        dealerHandString += card.getSuit();
    }
    return dealerHandString;
}

public void dealPlayer() {

    playerHand.add(deck.deal());

}

public void dealDealer() {

    dealerHand.add(deck.deal());

}

public String getDealerTopCard() {
    String dealerTopCard = "";
    card cardTop = dealerHand.get(0);
    card card = new card(cardTop.getValue(), cardTop.getSuit());
    dealerTopCard += "\n";
    dealerTopCard += card.getValue();
    dealerTopCard += "\t";
    dealerTopCard += card.getSuit();
    return dealerTopCard;

}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return  "\n" + game.name + "'s cards : " + getPlayerHand() + "\n\n " + game.name + "'s total: "
            + getPlayerHandValue() + "\n\n" + "Dealer is showing : "
            + getDealerHand();
}

public int getPlayerHandValue() {
    int playerHandValue = 0;        

    for (card a : playerHand) {
        String c = a.getValue();
        if (c.equals("J")) {
            playerHandValue += 10;
        }

        else if (c.equals("Q")) {
            playerHandValue += 10;
        }

        else if (c.equals("K")) {
            playerHandValue += 10;
        }

        else if (c.equals("A")) {
            playerHandValue += 11;
        }

        else {
            playerHandValue += Integer.parseInt(a.getValue());

        }
    }

    int valueOfCards = playerHandValue;
    return valueOfCards;
}

public int getDealerHandValue() {
    int playerHandValue = 0;        

    for (card a : playerHand) {
        String c = a.getValue();
        if (c.equals("J")) {
            playerHandValue += 10;
        }

        else if (c.equals("Q")) {
            playerHandValue += 10;
        }

        else if (c.equals("K")) {
            playerHandValue += 10;
        }

        else if (c.equals("A")) {
            playerHandValue += 11;
        }

        else {
            playerHandValue += Integer.parseInt(a.getValue());

        }
    }

    int valueOfCards = playerHandValue;
    return valueOfCards;
}

public void resetDealerHand() {
    dealerHand.clear();
}

public void resetPlayerHand() {
    playerHand.clear();
}

}
```

Let me know if I can provide you with anything else, thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Use debugger to see where your code is deviating from normal.

Comment: I've tried, I still can't seem to find anything wrong... I'm relatively new to java, which is why I've come here for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `getDealerHandValue()` is using the ArrayList `playerHand`.

It should be using the `dealerHand` ArrayList.

Even better would be to just define a method that takes a list as an arguement then just call it with the appropriate list, something like

```
public int getHandValue(List<card> theHand) {
    int handValue = 0;        

    for (card a : theHand) {
        // Your logic
    }
    return handValue;
}
```

Then call `getHandValue(playerHand)` or `getHandValue(dealerHand)`

Comment: haha thanks so much! I forgot to change them after I just copied it from above... I knew it'd be something stupid... Thanks for dealing with my idiocy:)